# Open source logger with client server architecture

Tags: c++, logging

I need a logger which has multiple client and one server. The server should be scalable.
The logging server can be of any language but client should be on C/C++. I will run in Linux flavor(ubuntu).please suggest  any open source solution which meets my requirement.

Comment: Isn't that just `syslog`?

Comment: (Not sure about scalability, it probably doesn't support running a cluster, but you could always partition your clients.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been fooling around with [making one myself](https://github.com/d-led/zmqlogger) based on g2log, but didn't really have time for it (it should be easy to build on Linux as well). But as far as I know, [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/) can append logs remotely already.

Comment: I installed the log4cxx in my system, but not sure that is it supports client/server architecture and scalability issue. My intention is to collect log from multiple process. I checked the user guide but unable to find any such information.

Comment: there is one already implemented: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4cxx/branches/mcatan/src/simplesocketserver.cpp
You should either try to dive into the log4cxx documentation, or build your own. Log4cxx has a [SocketAppender](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1net_1_1_socket_appender.html) class, which you can use from multiple clients to append to your logging server. Also, check out the related posts here on the right side.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your reply. But still I could not find out a simple Client server program which will run in Linux for log4cxx. The program I got either run in windows or some file/socketAppender missing in it.